# Is using base case variable in a recursive function important?

Tags: function, recursion, lua

I'm currently learning about recursion, it's pretty hard to understand. I found a very common example for it:

```lua
function factorial(N)
    local Value
    if N == 0 then 
        Value = 1 
    else
        Value = N * factorial(N - 1)
    end 
    return Value
end
print(factorial(3))
```

`N == 0` is the base case. But when i changed it into `N == 1`, the result is still remains the same. *(it will print 6)*.

Is using the base case important? (will it break or something?)

What's the difference between using `N == 0` (base case) and `N == 1`?

Comment: If you change the base case to `N == 1`, then `factorial(0)` will cause an endless loop. In every recursive function has to be a base case. So the recursion "knows" when to stop. There u have an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Factorial) how the factorial function resolves for N = 4.

Comment: Nice explanation and example, thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's just a coincidence, since `1 * 1 = 1`, so it ends up working either way.

But consider the edge-case where `N = 0`, if you check for `N == 1`, then you'd go into the else branch and calculate `0 * factorial(-1)`, which would lead to an endless loop.

The same would happen in both cases if you just called `factorial(-1)` directly, which is why you should either check for `> 0` instead (effectively treating every negative value as `0` and returning 1, or add another if condition and raise an error when `N` is negative.

---

EDIT: As pointed out in another answer, your implementation is not tail-recursive, meaning it accumulates memory for every recursive functioncall until it finishes or runs out of memory.

You can make the function tail-recursive, which allows Lua to treat it pretty much like a normal loop that could run as long as it takes to calculate its result:

```lua
local function factorial(n, acc)
   acc = acc or 1
   if n <= 0 then
      return acc
   else
      return factorial(n-1, acc*n)
   end 
   return Value
end
print(factorial(3))
```

Note though, that in the case of factorial, it would take you way longer to run out of stack memory than to overflow Luas number data type at around `21!`, so making it tail-recursive is really just a matter of training yourself to write better code.

Comment: Good to know, I already put " if N == 0 or N < 0 then" into my function. I didn't think about the negative number case.( treating every negative numbers like 0 seems fine with me)

Comment: you can just do `if N <= 0 then` in that case :D

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer and comments have pointed out, it is essential to have a base-case in a recursive function; otherwise, one ends up with an infinite loop.

Also, in the case of your factorial function, it is probably more efficient to use a helper function to perform the recursion, so as to take advantage of Lua's tail-call optimizations. Since Lua conveniently allows for local functions, you can define a helper within the scope of your factorial function.

Note that this example is not meant to handle the factorials of negative numbers.

```
-- Requires: n is an integer greater than or equal to 0.
-- Effects : returns the factorial of n.
function fact(n)
    -- Local function that will actually perform the recursion.
    local function fact_helper(n, i)
        -- This is the base case.
        if (i == 1) then
            return n
        end
        -- Take advantage of tail calls.
        return fact_helper(n * i, i - 1)
    end
    -- Check for edge cases, such as fact(0) and fact(1).
    if ((n == 0) or (n == 1)) then
        return 1
    end
    return fact_helper(n, n - 1)
end
```